# インラインコード内での HTML の扱いに関する説明と実装が食い違っている？

Tags: バグ, 翻訳, ヘルプ

### 不具合事象

[Markdown ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) を読んでいると、インラインコードの説明には、以下のように書かれています。私の翻訳が間違っていなければ、下記引用部の最後の文章 (太線にしました) には、「インラインコード内の HTML は手動でエスケープする必要がある」と書かれていると思います。

> #### インラインコード <sup>[[1]](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code-spans)</sup>
>
> Like code blocks, code spans will be displayed in a monospaced font. Markdown and HTML will not work within them. Note that, *unlike* code blocks, **code spans require you to manually escape any HTML within!**

しかし、`<strong>text</strong>` や `<del>text</del>` は実際のところ、私が**手動でエスケープしなくともエスケープされた状態で表示され**ます。確かに `code` 要素単体では、 `code` 要素内に「HTML 要素として解釈可能な文字列」があれば、それは HTML 要素として解釈されます。しかし、上記で引用した説明はMarkdown のインラインコードの説明なので、いきなり `code` 要素の特性について説明しているのであれば、不自然だと感じますし、それを書いておく意義もあまり無いと思います。

また、[`wmd.ja.js`](https://cdn.sstatic.net/js/wmd.ja.js) を読むと、インラインコードが生成される際、 `makeHtml` 関数が呼び出され、その中で `x` 関数が呼ばれていることがわかります。詳しい道程は省きますが、このようにして、インラインコード内の「HTML 要素として解釈可能な文字列」は**エスケープされています**。これは「インラインコード内の HTML は手動でエスケープする必要がある」という説明と食い違っています。

```
function x(e) {
    return e = e.replace(/&/g, "&amp;"),
    e = e.replace(/</g, "&lt;"),
    e = e.replace(/>/g, "&gt;"),
    e = M(e, "*_{}[]\\`~", !1)
}
```

---

### 改善案

もし当該箇所の英文の解釈に間違いが無ければ、この一文は不要であるため、削除してしまうことを提案します。ついでに翻訳案も載せておきます。

> #### インラインコード
>
> Like code blocks, code spans will be displayed in a monospaced font. Markdown and HTML will not work within them.
>
> ---
>
> #### インラインコード
>
> コードブロックと同様に、インラインコードも等幅フォントで表示されます。Markdown と HTML はインラインコード内で機能しません。

Comment: もしかすると `<code><sub>aaa</sub></code>` みたいなのがエスケープされない話と混同されて書かれたのかもしれないですね（実際されません）。探したら、英語版SOのメタで似たような投稿を見つけました: [Code formatting article in help center is confusing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348465/5989200)